# RESTAngular with factory method is not working

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Following the tips in
 [Best practice of RestAngular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593016/best-practice-of-restangular/28631245#28631245), I am trying to follow the suggestions (**Restangular Service - Factory** and **exampleService**) and it's not working.

The following source code includes two sections one. Without Angular Factory, that works. And with Factory that is not working:

```
<html ng-app="angularexample">
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-Controller='MainCtrl'>
            <div ng-repeat="user in users">
                Name : {{user.name}}<br>
                Age : {{user.age}}<br>
                ID : {{user.id}}<br>
                Change name:<input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/><button type="submit" ng-click="user.put()">Update</button><br/>
                Remove ID:<input type="text" ng-model="user.id"/><button type="submit" ng-click="user.remove()">Delete</button><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                add new: <br/>
                Name : <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.name"/><br/>
                Age : <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.age"/><br/>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">add</button>
            </div>                    
        </div>
        <div ng-Controller='ExampleCtrl'>

            My Title {{title}} <br/>
            <div ng-repeat="user in examples">
                Name : {{user.name}}<br>
                Age : {{user.age}}<br>
                ID : {{user.id}}<br>
                Change name:<input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/><button type="submit" ng-click="user.put()">Update</button><br/>
                Remove ID:<input type="text" ng-model="user.id"/><button type="submit" ng-click="user.remove()">Delete</button><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                add new: <br/>
                Name : <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.name"/><br/>
                Age : <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.age"/><br/>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">add</button>
            </div>                    
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/y22aBpcUwV1btrKB5jVM?p=preview

Here is the error screen:

http://i57.tinypic.com/334rfqu.jpg

The working reference is pictured as my REST service is not hosted . Yet my REST service is just having two fields namely - name and age.

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: This is the sample Model for Sails JS to create REST API.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name : {
            type : 'string'
        },
        age : {
            type : 'integer'
        }
    }
};
```

What could be an issue in my code? I would like to follow the best practices to build a big application.

Comment: followed the tip from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801731/angularjs-consuming-rest-api-with-restangular-in-a-factory

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/mQnQ0fz8ovj78dU6cTOH?p=preview is the solved example  and the working picture is here. http://i59.tinypic.com/s1mfck.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because your service methods do not return anything. Update them as follows:

```
// get examples from server by using Restangular
function getExamples(){
     return Restangular.all('user').getList();
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested this as the otherone works. Will try later. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the **then** method without returning the associated promise from your factory methods, you should return the promise, like

```
           // get examples from server by using Restangular
            function getExamples(){
               return Restangular.all('user').getList();
            }

            // get example with given id from server by using  Restangular
            function getExample(exampleId){
               return Restangular.one('user', exampleId).get();
            }
```

Now the methods will make the request and return the assoiciated promise on which you can call the **then** method.